# Is there any solution to solve range error while scraping table data from website?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, web-scraping

Step1: I have provided the directory of accessing the web data by storing it in a variable:

```
final response = await http.get(url);

dom.Document html = dom.Document.html(response.body);


final engTable = _getengFee(html.querySelectorAll(
    ' div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > table:nth-child(1)')[1]);
```

Step2: Now I have created a method

```
  static List<EngFee> _getengFee(dom.Element table) {
    return table.querySelectorAll('tr').sublist(1).map((e) {
      final tds = e.querySelectorAll('td');
      return EngFee(
        semester: tds[1].text.trim(),
        admFee: int.parse(tds[2].text.trim()),
        tuFee: int.parse(tds[3].text.trim()),
        examFee: int.parse(tds[4].text.trim()),
        miscFee: int.parse(tds[5].text.trim()),
        total: int.parse(tds[6].text.trim()),
      );
    }).toList();
  }
```

The output gives me an error

> E/flutter (13030): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1
>
> E/flutter (13030): #0      List.[] (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:260:36)
>
> E/flutter (13030): #1      _FeeStructureState.getFee (package:fee_scraper/screens/fee_scraper.dart:40:79)

Comment: Could you please paste your response body here?

Answer (score 0):

The error States that there is no value in list tds.

RangeError (index): Invalid value: Only valid value is 0: 1. This means the valid value is only 0 but you are checking for element at index 1.

To fix this you can check the length before accessing the element.

```dart
  final tds = e.querySelectorAll('td');
  return EngFee(
    semester: tds.length > 1? tds[1].text.trim():"", // this will check length and add empty string if the length is 0.
    admFee: tds.length > 2 ? int.tryparse(tds[2].text.trim()): 0,
```

Comment: But this line give me an error: admFee: tds.length > 2 ? int.parse(tds[2].text.trim()): "",     Error:The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'.